# xmlDocument on WebApi finding the last attribute

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

This is  the template code that is given to get the last node of an xml document

```
var highestAccount = (
from Accounts in xmlDocument.Elements("catalog").Elements("account")
orderby Accounts.Attribute("id").Value descending
select Accounts).Take(1);

   string highestId = highestAccount.Attributes("id").First().Value;

   string newId = "bk" + (Convert.ToInt32(highestId.Substring(2)) + 1).ToString();
```

but it is not working. The debugger cant capture it because its a webapi and no exception is given when the code starts.

This is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <catalog>
  <account id="1">
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>admin</password>
    <department>Admin</department>
  </account>
  <account id="bk">
    <username>sds</username>
    <password>dsds</password>
    <department>ds</department>
  </account>
</catalog>
```

It says there is an Internal Service Error but when I say

```
string newId = "123"
```

it will work like a charm. Please Help

Comment: You can absolutely debug inside a WebAPI service. 
Turn on Debug->Exceptions->Thrown->Common Language runtime exceptions.

Comment: I just tried it and it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is probably throwing a `FormatException`.  The first id you are getting from your select is "bk".  You then take the `Substring` starting at position 2, which is an empty string.  Convert.ToInt32 will throw an exception when given an empty string.

When you have a populated list of ids with the format of "bkNN", you are going to run into issues with OrderBy descending as well... A list like:

```
var idList = new List<String> {"bk1", "bk2", "bk3", "bk4", "bk5", 
    "bk6", "bk7", "bk8", "bk9", "bk10", "bk11"};
```

will be ordered descending as "bk9", "bk8", "bk7" ... "bk2", "bk11", "bk10", "bk1".

To get the behavior you are looking for, try something like this:

```
string newId = "bk" + 
    (idList.Where(id => id.StartsWith("bk") && id.Length > 2)
           .Select(id => Convert.ToInt32(id.Substring(2)))
           .OrderByDescending(id => id)
           .FirstOrDefault() + 1);
```

Comment: I tried making it  (highestId).ToString() but still does not work

Comment: Added fix for ordering issue and possible solution to next id generation.

Comment: Wait I will try :) Thanks for the reply, will edit the comment for results